# Why $\log_b(x)$ = $-\log_{1/b}(x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

IN a textbook I am asked to consider the graphs of $f(x) = \log_{1/2}(x)$ and $-\log_2(x)$. They appear identical and then the textbooks tells the rule that $\log_b(x)$ = $-\log_{1/b}(x)$.

I tried to prove this to myself on paper.

I can write both equations in exponential form. Pretend $x=4$:

$$\log_{1/2}(4)=\frac{1}{2}^y=4$$

Then write the same for the other version:

$$-\log_2(4)=-2^y=4$$

If I know these are equivalent then the two exponent versions should be the same no?

$$4=\frac{1}{2}^y=-2^y$$

It's not clicking and I don't 'get it' from here. Is my last equation true? Why are they equivalent?

Comment: Because $b^{-y}=(1/b)^y$.

Comment: Yes, as runway44 says, if $(1/b)^y = x$, then $b^{-y} = x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've written your formulas in a way that is confusing you.  You wrote  $$\log_{1/2}(4)=\frac{1}{2}^y=4$$ but what you actually meant was $$\log_{1/2}(4)=y \quad\text{ because }\quad \frac{1}{2}^y=4.$$

Then for the other version you have:

$$-\log_2(4)=-2^y=4$$

but it should be:

$$-\log_2(4)=y\quad\text{ because }\quad ???$$

Let's move that minus sign:

$$\log_2(4)=-y\quad\text{ because }\quad???$$

Okay, now it looks like the first one, and we get:

$$\log_2(4)=-y\quad\text{ because }\quad2^{-y} = 4.$$

And $2^{-y} = 2^{-1\cdot y} = \left(2^{-1}\right)^y = \left(\frac12\right)^y$.

I'm not sure that gives any intuition, but at least it shows where your mistake was.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x>0$, then $\log_b(x)$ is the unique real number such that $b^{\log_b(x)}=x$, but $b^{-\log_{1/b}(x)}=\frac{1}{b^{\log_{1/b}(x)}}=\left(\frac{1}{b}\right)^{\log_{1/b}(x)}=x$, therefore $-\log_{1/b}(x)=\log_b(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

We will use the following two identity
$$\log_a(b)=\log_{a^x}b^x$$
$$log_a(b^n)=n \log_a(b)$$

We will start with the question
$$log_b(x)=-log_{\frac 1 b}(x)$$
Seeing $\frac{1}{b}$ as the base in the right hand side of the equation motivates us to use the second identity setting up $x = -1$.
$$log_b(x)=-log_{\frac 1 b}(x)=-log_b(\frac{1}{x})$$
Now we get rid of the minus sign using the second identity
$$log_b(x)=-log_b(\frac{1}{x})=log_b((\frac 1 x)^{-1})=log_b(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

This comes from the following logarithmic identities:

$$\log(\frac{x}{y}) = \log(x)-\log(y)$$
$$\log_b(a)=\frac{\log_x(a)}{\log_x(b)}$$

where $x$ is any positive number (except 1).

Then you can calculate

$$\log_{1/b}(x) = \frac{\log_b(x)}{\log_b(1/b)} = \frac{\log_b(x)}{\log_b(1) - \log_b(b)}$$

Now remember that $\log_b(1)=0$ for any allowed base and $\log_b(b)=1$. So this simplifies to

$$\frac{\log_b(x)}{0 - 1} = -\log_b(x)$$

Comment: Did you mean $x$ is any positive number except $1$?

Answer (score 0):

$$log _{\frac 1 b} (x)=log _{\frac 1 b} (x)$$

$$x=(\frac 1b)^{log _{\frac 1 b} (x)}=b^{-log _{\frac 1 b} (x)}$$

We take log in base $\frac 1{\frac 1b}=b$ of both sides, we get:

$$log_b (x) =-log _{\frac 1 b} (x) log_b b=-log _{\frac 1 b} (x) $$

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=-\log_{1/b}(x)$. We see that
\begin{align}
&y=\log_{1/b}(x^{-1}) \\[4pt]
\implies&\left(\frac{1}{b}\right)^y=\frac{1}{x} \\[4pt]
\implies& \frac{1}{b^y}=\frac{1}{x} \\[4pt]
\implies& x=b^y \\[4pt]
\implies& y=\log_b(x) \, .
\end{align}